# Horizontal Slider is Missing in Latest Build of Jupyter Extension of VS Code

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter, horizontalscrollview

the Horizontal slider is missing after the recent update
whenever i am calling a show function in a Panda dataframe .I am not able to scroll right to see all columns after the recent update

Any idea how we can install old version of this extention

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer on the Jupyter extension team. Sadly this is just a bug that we hit moving over to our new UI implementation. You can see the issue tracking this here to follow along with a fix.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123816

Comment: Thank you ... Thankfully that Middle Button scroll is working . Thank you for sharing details